# new types may not be defined in a return type - C++

Tags: c++, class-design, compilation

I am confused I think on C++ class structure.

I have a .h called FxMathFunctions.h and a .cpp called FxMathFunctions.cpp

the .h starts like:

```
class  FxMathFunctions
{
    public:
        FxMathFunctions();
        ~FxMathFunctions();
```

and in the .cpp

I have:

```
#include "FxBasicTypes.h"
#include "FxMathFunctions.h"

FxMathFunctions::FxMathFunctions() {}

FxMathFunctions::~FxMathFunctions() {}
```

I am getting errors like:

```
error: new types may not be defined in a return type
error: return type specification for constructor invalid
```

This must be something to do with definition someplace, but I just dont see where this might occur.

Comment: I'm assuming that `FxMathFunctions` is properly closed in your code, i.e. it has a closing brace '}' followed by a semi-colon.  If not, I'd start there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ctor not allowed return type.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579657/ctor-not-allowed-return-type)

Comment: Apart from the ending semicolon, the `.h` file must start with an include guard, not with a class declaration.

Comment: @Philipp: Must is a bit strong. :) @JQZ: Telling us part of your code then asking for the the entire solution is rather unorthodox, don't you think?

Comment: @GMan - I dont know why you would phrase it like that. It was an obvious error on my part. Should I have posted all of the code?

Comment: @jDOG: Yes. The more code you post, the better we can help. There is a limit though: try to cut out unnecessary things. Too much code makes it hard for us to look for problems. But a partial file where the error is somewhere in the file is only allowing a partial answer.

Comment: @jDOG: Actually, you should trim back your code to the smallest bit of code that reproduces the _same_ error. Only then post that small bit. Often, you won't need to post at all; by eliminating clutter it becomes a lot easier for everyone including yourself to spot the bug.

Comment: thanks - had the same error and turns out when I converted a file from structured include to being a class, I didn't know it needed a closing semicolon.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

What does your .h file *end* with?  I'm guessing that the end of your class definition does not have a ";".  The class is being interpreted as the return type of the first function in your cpp file.

Answer (score 37):

Losing `;` in the end of class declaration could lead to such error.

Answer (score 17):

Class declaration ends with a semicolon.